# ConEmu and git for windows

Tags: git-bash, msys2, conemu

When I setup a tab in conemu to use {Bash: Git bash} it works for a while then I eventually get an error popup that says

"The code execution cannot proceed because msys-2.0.dll was not found"

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

After working with this, I may have found an answer.

It seems that the msys-2.0.dll exists in a number of places on my computer.

When I add a path entry for "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" it gives it access to the msys-2.0.dll that came with the bash that I am running.

Since I have done this, I have not had the issue recur.